# Return track-list using musicbrainzngs.search_releases()

Tags: python, musicbrainz

I'm getting acquainted with [musicbrainzngs](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/) and have run into a snag. All of the track-lists which are returned from the following are empty. Are there additional parameters I need to provide or is this a bug?

```
releases = musicbrainzngs.search_releases(
            query='arid:' + musicbrainz_arid
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. You have three ways of retrieving data from the MusicBrainz web service (using musicbrainzngs or directly):

1. [lookup/get](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#getting-data) info for one entity by id: lots of info for that id
2. [browse](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#browsing) a list of entities: possibility to get long list, medium amount of information
3. [search](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#searching) for entities: powerful to find things, but not much data given

When you know an entity by id you can look it up directly. You can even [add includes](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#getting-data) to get very detailed information.

When you not only want one entity, but a list (like a list of releases for one artist) you can [browse](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#browsing). Even for these you can add *includes*.

And only when you don't know the id of the entity (or an attached entity) *or* if you want to cut down the list of entities you [search](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#searching).

In your case you know the artist id and want to get the list of releases. In that case you should use [browse_releases](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#musicbrainzngs.browse_releases) and set an include for *recordings*:

```
releases = musicbrainzngs.browse_releases(artist=musicbrainz_arid,
                                          inc=["recordings"])
```